# Invalid Cast Exception of Logger in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

When I'm trying to run this command on `DBContext`:

```
await _myDbContext.SomeTableName.ToListAsync()
```

I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.Internal.DiagnosticsLogger`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbLoggerCategory+Database+Command]' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.IRelationalCommandDiagnosticsLogger'

Although, when I the `CanConnect()` check is returning `true` as well, I am able to execute raw SQL queries on the context.

I am using the below EF Core dependencies in my `.csproj`:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.20" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="6.0.20" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.20" />
```

My `startup.cs` part where I am registering EF Core looks like this:

```
builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>((serviceProvider, optionsBuilder) =>
{
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                    configuration.GetValue<string>(ConfigurationConstants.CONNECTION_STRING),
                    sqlServeroptionsBuilder => sqlServeroptionsBuilder.EnableRetryOnFailure())
    .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider)
    .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
 });
```

Comment: Something has to be wrong with your EFC related dependencies, even though what you have shown looks fine. Try removing all of them except the last one "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer", it should have transitive dependency (include) the others.  Do clean (also manually delete obj and bin folders if needed), rebuild and see if that helps.

Comment: It's really hard to debug something w/o having access to it. Try commenting out/removing `builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();` and `.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider)`, which are kind of "non standard". If it doesn't help, I surrender.

Comment: @IvanStoev this worked!!! thank you so much. Turns out the InternalServiceProvider was the culprit.